# html - como criar um botão que quando eu clicar nele aparecer outro

Tags: html, blogger

quero criar um botão que quando eu clicar nele realizar um ação por exemplo abrir um site e junto aparecer um botão abaixo.

tipo,para acessar o site clique nesse botão e depois que a pessoa clicar nele abrir um site e aparecer outro botão abaixo.

outro exemplo:  Para baixar clique neste botão e acesse o nosso site primeiro e depois que a pessoa clica e acessar o site aparecer o botão de download.

Me ajude...

Comment: Você pode usar uma função onclick (do JavaScript) para manipular o display do botão, que você quer exibir ao clicar no outro

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que essa solução é adequada para você:

HTML

```
<div>
  <button class = "b1">
    Clique-me!
  </button>

  <button class = "b2" style = "display: none;">
    Outro botão!
  </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var button = document.querySelector(".b1");
var button2 = document.querySelector(".b2");

button.onclick = function() {
 window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');
 button2.style.display = "block";
}
```

Ao clicar no botão `b1`, a função atrelada ao `onclick` abrirá uma nova aba e alterará o `display: none` para `display: block` do segundo botão, de classe `b2`.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xuuj2qv4/

Comment: é possivel adiciona codigo javascript em blogger html?

Comment: não consigo fazer o de html funcionar coquei o codigo de html e não pega

Comment: Sei que é possível, só não sei como exatamente. O HTML precisa do JavaScript para funcionar.